# How can I write different data into two different logs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I created two separate logs with two different names (windows). One is a rotating log and the other not. How can I prevent the data that I write to the rotating log from logging to the non-rotating log?

I am not very log savvy.

## importing module

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

def main():

    def normalLogging(fn1):
        global normalLogger
        #Create and configure logger
        logging.basicConfig(filename=fn1, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='w')

        #Creating an object
        normalLogger=logging.getLogger()

        #Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
        normalLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def rotatingLog(fn2):
        global rotatingLogger
        # start the roll-screen logger too
        rotatingLogger = logging.getLogger(fn2)
        rotatingLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # add a rotating logger
        handlerScreen = RotatingFileHandler(fn2, maxBytes=1000, backupCount=3)
        rotatingLogger.addHandler(handlerScreen)

    def normalTest():
        #Test messages to the rotating log
        normalLogger.debug("normalLogger.debug - Harmless debug Message")
        normalLogger.info("normalLogger.info - Just an information")
        normalLogger.warning("normalLogger.warning - Its a Warning")
        normalLogger.error("normalLogger.error - Did you try to divide by zero")
        normalLogger.critical("normalLogger.critical - Internet is down")

    def rotatorTest():
        for i in range(1, 100):
            #Test messages to the rotating log
            rotatingLogger.debug("rotatingLogger.debug %s - Harmless debug Message" % i)
            rotatingLogger.info("rotatingLogger.info %s - Just an information" % i)
            rotatingLogger.warning("rotatingLogger.warning %s - Its a Warning" % i)
            rotatingLogger.error("rotatingLogger.error %s - Did you try to divide by zero" % i)
            rotatingLogger.critical("rotatingLogger.critical %s - Internet is down" % i)

    # fn2 = "rotatorLog"
    rotatingLog("rotatorLog")
    rotatorTest()

    # fn1 = "normalLog"
    normalLogging("normalLog")
    normalTest()

    rotatorTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The rotating log maintains it's own unique data, but the normal log has data from the rotating log. I expected that the data would be unique to each log since I write to them separately, but that's not the case.

Comment: first use name for normal logger - `logging.getLogger(fn1)`. Next use `FileHandler` instead of `basicConfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: use name for normal logger - ie. `logging.getLogger(fn1)`

Second: use `FileHandler` instead of `basicConfig` for normal logger.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import FileHandler

def main():

    def normalLogging(fn1):
        global normalLogger
        global normalLogger

        normalLogger = logging.getLogger(fn1)
        normalLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        handlerScreen = FileHandler(fn1)
        handlerScreen.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
        normalLogger.addHandler(handlerScreen)

    def rotatingLog(fn2):
        global rotatingLogger

        rotatingLogger = logging.getLogger(fn2)
        rotatingLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        handlerScreen = RotatingFileHandler(fn2, maxBytes=1000, backupCount=3)
        handlerScreen.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
        rotatingLogger.addHandler(handlerScreen)

 # ... rest ...
```

As I remember `basicConfig` creates logger which later is used by all loggers so they use the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `rotatingLogger.propagate = False` to stop it's logs being sent to the root logger which is used for normalLogger. basicConfig configures the root logger and logging.getLogger without a name returns the root logger.